# Javascript in Firefox : onkeyup doesn't have a keyCode for the Control key

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onkeydown, onkeyup

I want to react to a key up event on my page and I need to know which key was released. The following code works fine in general but fails for the "Control" key: it alerts 0 instead of 17. The same code for the event key down works as expected.

```
document.onkeyup = function KeyUp(e)
{
    var keyCode = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
    alert(keyCode);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: works fine on [the test page](http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html), maybe there is something else interfering?

Comment: why don't you use `event.ctrlKey` flag ?

Comment: @jbabey the test page shows "0" for keyCode and which. I use Firefox 11.

Comment: @Diode I am interested in knowing whether the Ctrl key alone is released, not as a modifier.

Comment: It working for me ? Which version of FF do you use ?

Comment: @Diode Firefox 11 on RHEL 5. Must be this specific version because I can't reproduce with others.

Comment: event.ctrlKey is meant to be used as an indicator to know if the control key was pressed while the event happened... a keyup event will still fire when you release the control key with a keycode 17... as for why it fails? No idea... are you using a mac? that might have some influence, I don't know.

Comment: FF 16.0.2 @ Ubuntu 12.04 - working well, alerts 17.